# How to manage tags while working with multiple repositories

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have to manage tags for one project. This project contains three repositories:

- Desktop app (ElectronJS)
- Web app (React)
- Backend app (NodeJS)

Now after each build of the desktop app, I have to create a git tag. So, How to create a tag for all repo? Here, I'm confused because I have to create a tag for all the repos, not one repo.

Please suggest any solution for creating the tag for the whole project.

Comment: What is your actual issue here? If you need to tag all the repos... then tag them?

Answer (score 0):

A tag is an attribute of a specific commit on a single repository.

For that reason you cannot create tag across multiple repositories.

The only think you can do is to create the same tag on all of them.